# Getting com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException even when using TypeToken in android?

Tags: android, gson

I am trying to access `SharedPreferences` in my activity which I have stored as `JSON` strings of `HashMap`, but I am getting the error:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $.

**This is my code:**

```
private fun getTTROTData(grade: Int): HashMap<Pair<Int, Int>, String> {
    val ttrotPrefs = getSharedPreferences("TTROT", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val ttrotString = ttrotPrefs.getString(grade.toString(), null)
    Log.e("test", ttrotString)
    return if (ttrotString == null) HashMap() else {
        Gson().fromJson(ttrotString, object : TypeToken<HashMap<Pair<Int, Int>, String>>(){}.type)
    }
}
```

This is the log of the string I am trying to parse:

```
E/test: {"(2, 2)":"English"}
```

This is the complete log:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $.
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
        at tta.activities.TimeTableROT.getTTROTData(TimeTableROT.kt:91)
        at tta.activities.TimeTableROT.onShowTimeTable(TimeTableROT.kt:60)
        at tta.activities.TimeTableROT.onSelectClass(TimeTableROT.kt:50)
        at tta.fragments.rot.ROTClasses.onListItemClick(ROTClasses.kt:43)
        at androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:63)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1192)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3169)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:874)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $.
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:186) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841) 
        at tta.activities.TimeTableROT.getTTROTData(TimeTableROT.kt:91) 
        at tta.activities.TimeTableROT.onShowTimeTable(TimeTableROT.kt:60) 
        at tta.activities.TimeTableROT.onSelectClass(TimeTableROT.kt:50) 
        at tta.fragments.rot.ROTClasses.onListItemClick(ROTClasses.kt:43) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:63) 
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318) 
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1192) 
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3169) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:874) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

### EDIT

---

this line is also showing error for me:

```
Gson().fromJson("{\"(2, 2)\":\"English\"}", object : TypeToken<HashMap<Pair<Int, Int>, String>>(){}.type)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `HashMap<Pair<Int, Int>, String>` is indicating that you want the map key to be a pair, but according to your logged json it's actually a string.

You can enable the serialization of such a map key using [enableComplexMapKeySerialization](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization())

Careful that the structure of the serialized json changes and if you already have something stored in the shared preferences it will break.